# How to get the summation of diagonal lines using higher-order functions?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, higher-order-functions

Consider the following 2D array:

```
let array = [
                [11, 2, 4],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [10, 8, -12]
            ]
```

What I want to get is the summation of the diagonals:

- As `firstDiagnal`: 11 + 5 + (-12) = 4
- As `secondDiagnal`: 4 + 5 + 10 = 19

I could achieve it using a standard `for-in` loop:

```
var firstDiagnal = 0
var secondDiagnal = 0

for i in 0..<array.count {
    firstDiagnal += array[i][i]
    secondDiagnal += array[i][array[i].count - 1 - i]
}

print(firstDiagnal)
print(secondDiagnal)
```

However, what could it be if we tried to use *higher-order* functions? such as `map` and `reduce`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the first sum, you want the i'th element of the i'th row:

```
let firstDiag = array.enumerated().map { $1[$0] }.reduce(0, +)
```

To get the second sum, you want the same thing, but the columns reversed:

```
let secondDiag = array.enumerated().map { $1.reversed()[$0] }.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Wow. Nice answer. _clap_ _clap_ I was stuck thinking enumerated would iterate through the subarray also. _facepalm_

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you can write a neat extension to get the diagonal out of a nested array:

```
extension Array {

    func diagonal<T>(order: Int) -> [T] where Element == [T] {

        var order = order
        return self.compactMap {
            guard order >= 0, $0.count > order else {
                order -= 1
                return nil
            }
            let output = $0[order]
            order -= 1
            return output
        }
    }
}

let array = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]

print(array.diagonal(order: 0)) // [1]
print(array.diagonal(order: 1)) // [2, 4]
print(array.diagonal(order: 2)) // [3, 5 ,7]
print(array.diagonal(order: 3)) // [6, 8]
```

It's then just simply a case of the bog-standard reduce and sum:

```
let fristDiagonal = array.diagonal(order: 0).reduce(0, +)
let secondDiagonal = array.diagonal(order: 1).reduce(0, +)
```